# Problems installing Hydro

Tags: ros, installation, pcl, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trying to install Hydro i get the following problems.  When i try to install one by one and go deeper i find out that libpcl-1.7 has problems how can i solve this?
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
 ros-hydro-desktop-full : Depends: ros-hydro-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: ros-hydro-mobile but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: ros-hydro-perception but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: ros-hydro-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have fuerte working and i need it so i cant uninstall it, any ideas will be welcomed ;)
PD: Im installing hydro only to use the pcl-1.7 so if there is another way to use it and not install hydro that would work to

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/90756/problems-installing-hydro/) by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2013-10-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error suggests that you have packages being 'held' by apt.  Try searching that error.
I found [several](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages) potential [solutions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2113213)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0